# R: Is there a simple and efficient way to get back the list of building block matrices of a block-diagonal matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm looking for a (build-in) function, which efficiently returns the list of building blocks of a block-diagonal matrix in the following way (rather than iterating over the slots to get the list manually):

```
#construct bdiag-matrix
library("Matrix")
listElems <- list(matrix(1:4,ncol=2,nrow=2),matrix(5:8,ncol=2,nrow=2))
mat <- bdiag(listElems)

#get back the list
res <- theFunctionImLookingFor(mat)
```

The result `res` yields the building blocks:

```
[[1]]
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

**Edit**: Regarding my use case, the list elements in `listElems` are square and symmetric matrices. If the block is a diagonal matrix, `theFunctionImLookingFor` should return a list element for each diagonal element.

However, the function should be able to deal with building block matrices like

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    0    1    1
```

or

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

i.e. deal with zeros in blocks, which are not diagonal matrices.

Comment: You should be able to use `mat@i` for this. However, although my brain's pattern recognition is able to identify the blocks from something like `[1] 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4 5` (this is for a little bit more complex example) easily, I can't find a good algorithm right now.

Comment: What about `theFunctionImLookingFor <- list`? It always return one block... We need more details for this to be a well-posed problem.

Comment: @flodel They are looking for the inverse function of `bdiag`.

Comment: I understand and I maintain my argument. `mat` can be broken into many blocks, in what way is the one the OP chose special apart from the fact they are those that were used to build `mat` (that info is lost, isn't it?).

Comment: @flodel To me this is a very well posed problem. They want to extract the blocks from a block-diagonal sparse matrix.

Comment: The problem boils down to how can I transform `[1] 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4 5` into "two times two consecutive numbers , three times three consecutive number, one time one number" efficiently.

Comment: @Roland, if you can explain why `theFunctionImLookingFor <- list` is not a valid solution, then maybe you'll be able to make this a well-posed problem in my eyes. I think it would have to be "we are trying to maximize the number of blocks in the output".

Comment: @flodel The question is: "How can I get the list that has been passed to `bdiag` from the block-diagonal sparse matrix?" Hint: The result doesn't contain the "non-existent"  elements of the sparse matrix.

Comment: What should be the length of `theFunctionImLookingFor(bdiag(list(diag(3))))`?

Comment: @flodel I'd say three. Otherwise this gets really complicated. We should probably also constrict this to square blocks (`bdiag` allows non-square matrices).But I'm not the OP.

Comment: @flodel: good question. As the list in the bdiag-call is assumed to have length `>=2`, the resulting list of your example should have length 3. I think the zeros within blocks are the trickiest part.

Comment: @DavidR Please edit your question and provide a representative example.

Comment: Here is my first attempt, which seems much to be too complicated and does not work, if blocks contain zeros: `nonZeros <- which(!!mat, arr.ind=TRUE); getGroup <- c(0,cumsum(as.numeric(apply(apply(nonZeros,2,diff),1,function(x)diff(x)==0))));indM <- lapply(split(1:(nrow(nonZeros)),getGroup),function(x)c(min(x),max(x)));lapply(indM,function(ind,matr,nZ){ rws=nZ[ind,][,1];cls=nZ[ind,][,2];matr[rws[1]:rws[2],cls[1]:cls[2]]} ,matr=mat,nZ=nonZeros)`

Comment: @Roland: Sorry, the last comment regarding the non-square matrices was an error in reasoning. You are right. Let's constrict this to square blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this will work for all your cases, the test at the bottom includes a block that contains zeroes.

```
theFunctionImLookingFor <- function(mat, plot.graph = FALSE) {
   stopifnot(nrow(mat) == ncol(mat))
   x <- mat
   diag(x) <- 1
   edges <- as.matrix(summary(x)[c("i", "j")])
   library(igraph)
   g <- graph.edgelist(edges, directed = FALSE)
   if (plot.graph) plot(g)
   groups <- unique(Map(sort, neighborhood(g, nrow(mat))))
   sub.Mat <- Map(`[`, list(mat), groups, groups, drop = FALSE)
   sub.mat <- Map(as.matrix, sub.Mat)
   return(sub.mat)
}

listElems <- list(matrix(1:4,ncol=2,nrow=2),
                  matrix(5:8,ncol=2,nrow=2),
                  matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),ncol=3,nrow=3),
                  matrix(1:1,ncol=1, nrow=1))

mat <- bdiag(listElems)

theFunctionImLookingFor(mat, plot.graph = TRUE)
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4

# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    5    7
# [2,]    6    8

# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    1    1

# [[4]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, flodel! I've never heard of the igraph package before: Is there a way to parallelize the calculations? So far, my ad-hoc solution is still 7 times faster using parallel:::mclapply with 10 cores.

Comment: Can you provide details about your problem's size?

Comment: The dimension of `mat` ranges between 1 and approx. 1e6. The posted result (49 seconds vs. 7 seconds - so not really a big deal) of computation time refers to an example with `dim(mat)=1e4`. However, as there are a few more steps after the decomposition of the matrix, which also could be parallelized, I would prefer such a solution.

Comment: That's not working for me... Error in .Primitive("[")(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]],  : 
  invalid or not-yet-implemented 'Matrix' subsetting

Comment: @statquant replace `sub.Mat <- Map(`[`, list(mat), groups, groups, drop = FALSE)` with `sub.Mat <- Map(`[`, list(as.matrix(mat)), groups, groups, drop = FALSE)`

Comment: solution ignores diagonal blocks in the matrix `Matrix::bdiag(Matrix::Diagonal(2), matrix(1:3, 3,3), diag(3:2))` returns 7 elements