# Fill in bigger matrix by smaller submatrices

Tags: r, matrix

I need to create  a bigger matrix using smaller submatrices in a following way. These smaller submatrices come out of the model that I have and they could be either 1x1,2x2, 3x3 4x4 or 5x5. The dimension of the new square matrix would be determined from the sum of number of columns of all submatrices. For example below we have 1x1,2x2 and 1x1 matrix so the dimension of the larger matrix would be 4x4 (1+2+1=4). The problem is that I need to do this recursively 50 times. Each time I will have a bunch of submatrices of different dimensions and I need to make a bigger matrix like above using those smaller submatrices. I will really appreciate any help.

```
  A1<-runif(1)

  A <- matrix(runif(4), 2, 2)
  A2<- A %*% t(A)

  A3<-runif(1)
  A4<-matrix(runif(4),2,2)
  new.mat<-matrix(c(A1,0,0,0,0,A2[1],A2[2],0,0,A2[3],A2[4],0,0,0,0,A3),nrow=4,ncol=4)

 A1
[1] 0.8754123
 A2
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.9307090 0.3919325
[2,] 0.3919325 0.3857751
 A3
[1] 0.323764
     new.mat
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
  [1,] 0.8754123 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000
  [2,] 0.0000000 0.9307090 0.3919325 0.000000
  [3,] 0.0000000 0.3919325 0.3857751 0.000000
  [4,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.323764
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26773290/r-is-there-a-simple-and-efficient-way-to-get-back-the-list-of-building-block-ma The package `Matrix` has a function `bdiag()` to construct blockdiagonal matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with base R to construct the blockdiagonal matrix:

```
set.seed(42)
A1<-runif(1)

A <- matrix(runif(4), 2, 2)
A2<- A %*% t(A)

A3<-runif(1)

L <- list(A1, A2, A3)

n <- sum(sapply(L, function(a) nrow(as.matrix(a))))
AAA <- matrix(0, n, n)

start <- 1
for (i in 1:length(L)) {
  ni <- nrow(as.matrix(L[[i]]))
  AAA[start:(start+ni-1), start:(start+ni-1)] <- L[[i]]
  start <- start+ni
}
```

It is better to have the submatrices in a List, so I start with `L <- list(A1, A2, A3)`. The rest is using index ranges. Here is the result:

```
> AAA
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.914806 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[2,] 0.000000 1.5677536 0.8010704 0.0000000
[3,] 0.000000 0.8010704 0.4937131 0.0000000
[4,] 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5190959
```

#### package Matrix:

The package `Matrix` has a function `bdiag()` to construct blockdiagonal matrices.